# Calendar.MONTH and internal working

Tags: java, calendar

I have a little question about internal java working and Calendar, i dont understand why when i use for example:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mesInt = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); 
    System.out.println(mesInt);
```

If then i print mesInt, if the actually month is february i obtain mesInt = 1;

is there any special reason for that? I would like to know because i had problems before with my database, and i would like if it is possible to know the solution of start by 0 the month.

Thanks for all, and sorry if the questions is duplicated i haven not found it.

PD: i know that is zero-based, but i would like to know the real reason for that.

PD2: sry for my bad english. I know the solution i would like to know the reason of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation states the first month is 0.

> i would like to know the real reason for that.

I suspect starting at 0 is easier to calculate.  I am not sure any one person will admit to designing Calendar. Perhaps it made sense at the time as many of the numberings for years, AM/PM etc start at 0.  BTW days of the week start at 1.

> know i would like if it is possible to know the solution.

Use

```
int mesInt = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
```

BTW For me the strange one is UNIDECIMBER when uni-deci mean 11 not 13.

Comment: I was thinking something about the number of the days but i dont obtein any posstive conclusion. I know the soluton jejeje, i would like to know the concret reason for that jejeje.

Comment: Unidecimber is another mistery in calendar, perhaps they prepared a calendar for other planet?  Perhaps because all index in java start at 0? That could be an esays solution for that, sometimes occam razor us the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Months are 0 based. I'm not sure of the reason why...

So when using either `get` or `set` with month you need to remember to either +1 or -1 as required.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int mesInt = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, mesInt - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Months in `Calendar` starts from `zero` it means that `January -> 0` `February -> 1` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Specification of Calendar.MONTH is as follows:

Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.

Essentially for all practical purposes : January is 0 and December is 11.

Answer (score 0):

I bet it's for the same reason array indices start from 0. It's just how it is. February is often displayed as "2", but displaying or printing values is different from using them in code.